# pulling key by place from dictionary using pandas

Tags: dictionary, pandas, ipython

I already know you can pull specific keys from dictionary objects in pandas if you already know the exact value for the key, but what if you wanted to pull the median key's values of a dictionary without knowing the value (or in this case, author name)?

ex.

```
author name:   books:                                year:
fred           how to fish                           2010
               how to bike                           2012
               how to skate                          2009
bob            sam I am                              1990
george         white fang                            1980
               animals and I                         2000
ted            a guide to computer programming       1984
harry          the future queen                      1812
```

So I would want to get the median author name. There are five authors, so the 3rd author is the one I want (george), and just print all the data associated with him. Then eventually I'd also want to print the number of books he's published (which is two). Do I have to convert the dictionary object back to a csv file or something? Tips or helpful tutorials anyone knows on pandas dictionary objects would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were taking about an integer/float column then you can just use the median method:

```
In [11]: df['year:'].median()
Out[11]: 1995.0
```

#### However, this isn't well-defined for a column of strings, at least using the normal definition*.

If you just want the "middle" item then just take that (I'm not sure what you want to do with a draw...):

```
In [12]: df['author name:'].iloc[int(len(df) / 2.)]
Out[12]: 'george'
```

*Note: it actually **is** a draw in this case...*

Or you can get the unique names (in the order they were given, ignoring repeats out of order), again you have to worry about draws:

```
In [13]: names = df['author name:'].unique()

In [14]: names
Out[14]: array(['fred', 'bob', 'george', 'ted', 'harry'], dtype=object)

In [15]: names[int(len(names) / 2.)]
Out[15]: 'george'
```

* What's half way between 'bob' and 'george'?

Comment: haha, halfway between bob and george would probably be something like 'obgeo' or 'bobgeorge' --> 'e'. Quick question though - by doing 'names = df['author name:'].unique()', would that get rid of all books an author wrote except for the one attached to the first instance of his name?

Comment: @user2635779 yep, that exactly right! ...it was unclear what you wanted so threw that out there.

Comment: I answered my own question - so this one utilizes the array, which is nice, but I'm going to post the simpler solution that uses .dict caused by pandas Groupby function as a separate answer in case others were curious.

Comment: @user2635779 cool, don't forget to upvote now you have the power :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found after going through a tutorial (link posted on bottom of answer)

```
df = pd.read_csv('location', etc...)  #### data taken from csv file
stats1 = df.groupby('author name').agg({'books': [np.size]})
x = int(len(stats1) / 2.)
print stats1[(x-1):(x)]
```

based off of this tutorial:
http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/using-pandas-on-the-movielens-dataset/

Comment: I think you can do df.groupby()['books'].size() directly, but be aware that both these solutions may return in a different order than they appear in df.